# desenvolvimento app ordenação, firebase android

Tags: android, banco-de-dados, firebase, classificação, android-recyclerview

boa noite galera queria tirar uma duvida, estou desenvolvendo uma app, e uso firebase mas sou meio leigo ainda na programação, em fim queria saber se tem alguma forma de ordenar os dados que vem do firebase no recyclerview em forma de cards, se alguem puder me passar um exemplo agradeço. muito obrigado...

Comment: amigos ja foi resolvido meu problema, alguém entendeu a pergunta!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voce pode usar orderByChild. Exemplo:

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();   
Query peopleTypeQuery = mDatabase.child("people").orderByChild("age");

peopleTypeQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

    @Override public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {

    }
});
```

ele ordenara pelo valor da key "age"

Comment: obrigado vou colocar no meu codigo, depois de ordenar se eu querer colocar em determinados campos exemplo categoria e comparar com a key se key for igual tal categoria retorna categoria tal, vc poderia me ajudar nessa logica, ja agradeço

Comment: ai tem que criar as condições(if), abre outra pergunta com trechos onde você quer ajuda por lá eu consigo ajudar melhor.

Comment: okay Edson.....